# Android pass View as an object to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm more googling to find how can i pass simple `view` as an object to fragment, but i can't.

for example in MainActivity i have simple view as :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findviewById(R.id.tv_text);
```

now i want to pass that to fragment. this below code is my attach Fragment on MainActivity

`MainActivity` :

```
public void attachFragment() {
    fts = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFragment = new FragmentMarketDetail();
    fts.replace(R.id.cardsLine, mFragment, "FragmentMarketDetail");
    fts.commit();
}
```

and  this is my `Fragment`:

```
public class FragmentMarketDetail extends Fragment implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {
    public static final String SCROLLVIEW_STATE = "scrollviewState";
    private ObservableScrollView scrollViewTest;
    private Context    context;
    private int scrollY;

    public static FragmentMarketDetail newInstance() {
        FragmentMarketDetail fragmentFirst = new FragmentMarketDetail();
        return fragmentFirst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_online_categories, container, false);
        scrollViewTest = (ObservableScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewTest);
        scrollViewTest.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about adding a set function in your custom fragment
e.g.

```
public void setTextView(TextView tv){
    this.tv = tv
}
```

and then calling it after

```
mFragment = new FragmentMarketDetail();
mFragment.setTextView(textView)
```

Answer (score 5):

It wouldn't be good practise to pass a view that way. If you want to access the view in your activity from within your fragment class, use `getActivity()` to access the activity to which your fragment is attached, and from there you find your TextView.

```
TextView text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find fragment by tag and invoke a function on it:

```
mFragment = (FragmentMarketDetail ) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentMarketDetail .class.getSimpleName());
mFragment.passTextView(textView);
```

Of course fragment must be added to backstack.